# How to add paths in ubuntu

Tags: c++, libraries, paths

I know that this is a very popular question with a lot of threads already about it, but unfortunately after trying some of the suggestions I didn't manage to solve my problem, so I am posting a new question about it.
What I am interested in, is running a c++ program in terminal, the thing is, as I was always using eclipse to compile and run programs I am completely noob on this and also my ubuntu knowledge is limitated to very basic things.
So what I am finding difficulties in is when I want to compile a program which needs to include some header files form different directories. What I want to do is to include this libraries without needing to add in the #include "..." the whole path of where the library is but just it's name.
In Eclipse this could be done by adding paths through options, but in Ubuntu I am not really sure how to do so, following some instructions in other threads I tried to add the paths to my ~/.profile txt file but without any success.
So I would like to ask how is this possible to be done, i.e. where and how to add the paths of the header files needed so that I want have all the time for very new project to provide the entire path in my includes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the path with `-I` arguments to `g++` for example,

```
$ cat /home/efrisch/t/myheader.h
#include <iostream>
$ cat hello.cc
#include "myheader.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
}
$ g++ -O -I/home/efrisch/t hello.cc -o hello
$ ./hello
Hello, World!
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this wouldn't be of much help to me.
I need a way to include for example the "/home/efrish/t/myheader.h" without having to write the path inside the programme this is because I have hundreds of header folders I need to include, so I just need a way to include the paths of where the header files are

Comment: @user3111197 Yes. You pass them on the command line to g++ like I demonstrated. "/home/efrisch/t" is a different folder from where `hello.cc` is.

Comment: Ok now got it, one more really stupid thing (I am not in my machine with ubuntu and I can't try them myself that's why I have to ask the following stupid thing as well) about the syntax for including more than one folders say "/home/efrisch/t" and "/home/efrisch/s" the correct syntax for it is:
$ g++ -O -I/home/efrisch/t -I/home/efrisch/s hello.cc -o hello
?

Comment: @user3111197 **Yes**! If you have the same include in both folders `t` and `s` then `t/whatever.h` will shadow `s/whatever.h`; so you might reverse the order.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for the help I will try it tomorrow and see if it works.

Comment: That worked just fine, once again thanks a lot!

Comment: @user3111197 Glad to hear it! Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer then.

Comment: Oops, sorry I am completely noob on this staff

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thanks. your solution is work for me. How could I add these libraries and header to library  variable path in ubuntu?